# Как сохранить куки в БД?

Tags: php, cookie, база-данных

Есть личный сайт, браузер тупит. Надоело каждый раз вводить пароль, можно ли как-то кук сохранить в БД?

Comment: > Есть сайт браузер тупит

Что?

Comment: Такие вопросы порой что мозг просто взрывается!

Comment: во общем куки хочу в БД хранить чтоб все время не ввести пароли, вот такая дуратская идея

Comment: идея правильная, или генерите сами куку или используйте сессии, которые тоже с помощью куков сделаны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то вроде ($name - имя кука)

```
$vals = '';
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (val1, val2) VALUES(";
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $cookie)
    $vals .= "'$cookie'";
$query .= $vals.")";
```

Answer (score 4):

Как же собрались их оттуда получать? Вот допустим вы сохранили их там, но куков у вас все равно нет чтобы сервер понял что это ваши куки...

Answer (score 1):

Не проще задавать более долгое время жизни кук?